# Is it ok to delete an abstract class instead of a child?

Tags: c++, inheritance, abstract-class

Is it ok to delete an abstract class instead of a child? Will all allocs be deallocated thereby?

Consider a following situation as an example, but please do not limit your answers to that one case:

```
struct A {
    virtual void fun() = 0;
};
struct B : public A {
    void fun() { /* actually doing something here. */ }
};
struct C {
    A *a;
    void OneTask() {
        // (...)
        a = new B();
    }
    void AnotherTask() { /* using fun() in some way. */ }
    ~C() { delete a; }
};
```

The idea is to have multiple possible outcomes of OneTask() which result in an assignment of a pointer to different classes that inherit from A, B being just an example; and then to use such result reasonably in AnotherTask() and other methods of class C.

Comment: You should read about [When to use virtual destructors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/461203/when-to-use-virtual-destructors).

Comment: @Dariusz In order to spare my time and lines writing "public:"

Comment: @yauser Do you understand the importance of OOP? Or I should say risk of not using encapsulation?

Comment: @Joe of course I do but do you *really* think that I should use encapsulation in the purposefully simplified example I provided?

Comment: Fair enough, the less code the better for posting here. We were just looking out for you.

Comment: @Joe True, thank you, that would be indeed alarming if someone would consider actually coding in that manner ;)

Answer (score 2):

You must have virtual destructor in base class else complete destruction of derived class doesn't happen.

```
struct A {
    virtual void fun() = 0;
virtual ~A()
   {
    }
};
```

Comment: I understand and will bear that in my heart, but would the complete destruction really fail even for my trivial example?

Comment: yes it will fail. You can verify by defining destructor and putting "cout" message. you can observe that derived class destructor is not called.

Comment: Formally, the behavior is undefined if you delete an object of a derived type through a pointer to a base that does not have a virtual destructor.

Comment: And often that means calling the _least_ derived dtor which is still implemented (in optimized builds), because that's the last one which could legally be called. That's why @shivakumar's test is troublesome: the result depends on optimizer behavior, and it will assume no Undefined Behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's perfectly fine to `delete a` without knowing what actual derived type `a` is pointing to.

As shivakumar pointed out, if you don't make your base class's destructor virtual, then deleting a derived class will not end up calling the base class's destructor.  In your trivial example that's not a problem, but in real life you should always make your destructors virtual.

Answer (score 0):

If A has a virtual destructor then both  destructors of A and B are succesfully called (first B then A) ,

If you do not declare the constructor of A as virtual, then only the destructor of A is called during deletion and extended data of B may leak.

```
struct A {
   virtual void fun() = 0;
   virtual ~A();
};
struct B : public A {
   void fun() { /* actually doing something here. */ }
   ~B();
};
```

Comment: But if I do not add any further fields in children classes, only new methods, then no leaks are possible, right?

Comment: @yauser Yes, that is right, but also you can not use the destructor of B for any purpose like terminating some operation.